# SQL Server 2005 into Excel with OPENROWSET MSG 7399/7303

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, export-to-excel, openrowset

My patience is at an end with this issue. I run jobs via SSMS or the agent that have been working perfectly fine up until last week that insert data from tables/views into various Excel files.

Most recently, the jobs/code just keep running while never finishing...these jobs use to only take up-to 15-25 seconds to complete but now never end. I've tested the code below on a new sheet and it goes instantaneously! The error I'm getting also doesn't help, the solutions I've found in Google were no help or were already set.

Any ideas what would cause a openrowset export to just bomb out and not do its job?

Code I generally run that works:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Database=C:\Automation\DYNAMIC\Output\File.xlsx;',
'SELECT * FROM [Data$]')

SELECT *
FROM [REPORTING].[dbo].[tbl_table]
```

The current error message:

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information
>   about the error.
>   Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

System:

- SQL Server 2005 32-Bit on Windows XP 32-Bit

Updated/Edited information:

- Excel sheets contain either functions on a separate tab or Charts extrapolating the data from the [Data$] tab (if any of this helps)
- I have created a brand new worksheet and tested my insert query and it worked perfectly
- The source file was not originally created on the server, but instead transferred via Share Drive (I don't think this would matter though)

Any help is appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: You may have done all this, but: 1. Do the filenames that fail contain space characters? 2. Try renaming a failing file, create a "new sheet" with the same path and name as the failure, and INSERT. Does that work? (If so, the contents of the file is the likely problem.) 3. Does this work with explicit column name lists, not SELECT *? 4. If you "Save As.." one of the failing Excel files under a new name, can you insert into it? Have you opened the Excel files that fail and checked the Data$ range very carefully (then closed it of course, before querying)? 6. Does SELECT from OPENROWSET work?

Comment: @Steve - Thanks for responding. 1) No, it has underscores to represent spaces. 2) Does not work  3) No 4) No and yes 6) No, it just executes forever.  I have however created a brand new test.xlsx with [Sheet1$] as the destination, inserted the same data i wanted for the other sheet and it worked instantly!  I'll append the above question but also place here - does it have anything to do with me having a few tabs with Charts in it? I also have the same issue with another file (different directory) that has no charts, just some functions. That one for sure has worked before. At a lost here

Comment: More guessing: To verify that SQL Server can even "see" the problem file, does this return a result?

select * from openrowset(BULK N'C:\Automation\DYNAMIC\Output\File.xlsx',single_blob) as T

I'm still fuzzy on what does and doesn't work. To #2 earlier, you said renaming the bad file and creating a new one (but I was unclear with "sheet" vs. "file") does NOT work.

Is the following right (If not, can you clarify what failed in #2 before)?
a) You can insert into Sheet1$ of a brand new C:\Automation\DYNAMIC\Output\test.xlsx, but
b) You canNOT insert into a brand new file with the problem name.

Comment: Yes a blob result is returned with BULK. #2) I can insert into a brand new file that has a different file name. I cannot insert into the file with the same name but as a new workbook. And I cannot insert into a new Sheet of the original bad workbook. I guess SQL is blocking these files for whatever reason? It's interesting to say the least...but a pain in the...

Comment: It sounds like the entire problem is with the file name, then. From what you've said, you have no problem using a different file name and you always have problems with the existing file name (regardless of whether the .xlsx file is new or old). Since BULK returns data, it sounds like a strange bug with the ACE driver. Maybe the underscores in the file names are a problem? The solution is to use a different naming convention for the Excel files. Hopefully that's an option for you.

Comment: Well somethings are never easy Steve...lol...It appears it was a possible combination of the underscores + past queries executing in the background (sp_who2) and after a restart I could insert once again into dummy files...trying to run against the same file that I renamed and again getting the MSG 7399/7303 error messages from the above post...any more ideas? I tried both the Select * Insert and manually identifying the column names that are in the worksheet...

Comment: I have a guess. OPENROWSET presumably has to lock the Excel file to insert; maybe the lock isn't released until you restart the server. I can't test where I am, but I think you error is the same as with an Excel file that's open on a PC. I found a discussion claiming that if the OPENROWSET query is inside a transaction, the file lock will never be released. It's here (search the page for "lock"): http://database.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/sql-server-l/import-data-from-a-spreadsheet-using-openrowset-3844021. Do the problem files appear in Excel's recovery pane ever?

Comment: THe lock statement is true, but it only kept the lock when it was in a "continuos" execution state of the query until I manually killed it or the server got a forced restart, but sp_who2 shows its not running. No the files have never appeared in the recovery. I just did a test on test.xlsx - its a brand new workbook, i inserted the data and made a chart off of it. Deleted the data, leaving the chart formula intact and re-ran the insert getting the error I have now. maybe it's a MS flaw. tested my 1st report that has an _ in the filename and basic formulas and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same issue and what seemed to correct it was restarting SQLServer Service